# compiling with neato issue

Tags: linux, graphviz, neato

I'm trying to output a very simple graph (3 aligned nodes) as a png using neato.
The source file, starts with:

```
graph {
  graph [size="8,5"];
  node [label="\N", pin=true, shape=circle];
  0 [pos="0,0", pin=true, style=filled];
  1 [pos="0,60", pin=true, style=filled];
  2 [pos="0,120", pin=true, style=filled];
  1 -- 0;
  2 -- 1;
  3 -- 2;
}
```

Unfortunately, the label of the nodes (1,2,3) isn't shown in the output image (png).
The very same source file produces a different result when run from another Unix computer, but I'm failing to see what library or configuration could be different.
Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: If it's only three nodes, can you just post the full source?

Comment: Also, what version of graphviz are you using (on the system where it works and the system with the problem)?

Comment: graph{
graph [size="8,5"];
node [label="\N", pin=true, shape=circle];
0 [pos="0,0", pin=true, style=filled];
1 [pos="0,60", pin=true, style=filled];
2 [pos="0,120", pin=true, style=filled];
1 -- 0;
2 -- 1;
3 -- 2;
} I don't have access to the other system where it works, but I have the output png it generated. On my machine, the version is neato - Graphviz version 2.20.2 (Tue Mar  2 19:03:41 UTC 2010)

Comment: Using `dot - Graphviz version 2.20.2 (Tue Nov 16 00:59:27 UTC 2010)` on your file works.

Comment: Yes indeed it does, thanks. What's the difference between dot and neato, does it do any harm if I use dot instead ? And why would that file work on another computer ? Is it just a version problem ? What version should I install then ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it render correctly if you remove your explicit size and positioning information?  That is, if you give it...

```
graph {
  node [label="\N", pin=true, shape=circle, style=filled];
  0;
  1;
  2;
  1 -- 0;
  2 -- 1;
  3 -- 2;
}
```

...do the node labels show up correctly?  This input renders correctly for me under both graphviz 2.28.0 and 2.12.

Comment: Yes in that case the labels do show up, but the extra information is there for something, I want to place the nodes according to what I asked.